# I would like to check if an input is python code

Tags: python, python-2.7, exec, python-2.x

I would like to check if an input is code before joining it to a larger variable to eventually execute, is there any way I can do this?
For example:

```
import readline
while True:
    codelines=[]
    code=raw_input(">>> ")
    if code.iscode():
        codelines.append(code)
    elif x=="end":
        break
    else:
        print "Not usable code."
fullcode="\n".join(codelines)
try:
    exec fullcode
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

But I know of no command that works like `.iscode()`

Comment: I would be VERY careful allowing a user to enter code that will be run. I would recommend removing certain words like `import` from any entered text. To avoid things like this `__import__('os').system('rm -rf /')` from being run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try parsing the input with [`ast.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse):

```
import ast
while True:
    codelines=[]
    code=raw_input(">>> ")
    try:
        ast.parse(code)  # Try to parse the string.
    except SyntaxError:
        if x=="end":  # If we get here, the string contains invalid code.
            break
        else:
            print "Not usable code."
    else:  # Otherwise, the string was valid.  So, we add it to the list.
        codelines.append(code)
```

The function will raise a `SyntaxError` if the string is non-parseable (contains invalid Python code).

Comment: Of course, you are aware that accepting user input and executing it (whether in Python or sql or whatever) is just a massive security risk?  Especially with Python which can easily do something very nasty by invoking system level commands.  "import shutil;  shutil.rmtree("~")", for example.

Comment: I just want to reiterate what @JLPeyret said. It is EXTREMELY risky to accept user input that will be run.

Comment: +1 for @JLPeyret - if your design needs arbitrary input of python code, rethink your design - maybe implementing a subset ...

Comment: The documentation says it creates a code object which can be passed to `exec`. Does that mean it isn't executed? And the failure is purely syntactical?

Comment: @PeterWood - Yes, that is correct.  `ast.parse` will not execute the string, only parse it into a code object.